# Remove this bubble or pop-up window from my screen

Tags: windows-7

I have the following that won't go away, I've always wondered how to remove it without restarting.

[image]

Is there a way to reboot just my screen view?

Comment: What browser are you using? Historically, i've always found that right clicking over/near the area of the bubble seems to make it disappear.

Comment: It is looking same as appeared in MS Word or other MS Office application hyperlink..isn't it? I'll then suggest to open that file in which this link appears and then close it after moving cursor near the bubble

Comment: Ok seems closing outlook it still stayed there then re-opening it it disappeared, bit weird but least its gone was getting in the way of my work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting the window manager:

1. `Control Panel` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `Services`
2. Right-click on `Desktop Window Manager Session Manager` and select `Restart`

This will make your screens flash for a bit, but it should do a decent job of resetting the windowing manager and clear out unparented tooltips.